# How to unit-test a Wicket component with AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior?

Tags: java, unit-testing, wicket

I have a Wicket panel that has [AbstractAjaxTimeBehavior](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior.html), that I'd like to unit test. How can I trigger a ajax event during the unit test that end up calling `AbstractAjaxTimeBehavior`'s `.onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target)` method?

```
behavior = new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(pollingPeriodInSeconds)) {
  protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
     // how to unit test this?
  }
}
add(behavior);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the timer behavior won't fire itself as in the browser, you'll have to use [executeBehavior(AbstractAjaxBehavior)](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/BaseWicketTester.html#executeBehavior%28org.apache.wicket.behavior.AbstractAjaxBehavior%29) yourself.

```
if (!timerBehavior.isStopped())
  wicketTester.executeBehavior(timerBehavior);
```

Just have a look at the code of `executeAllTimerBehaviors(MarkupContainer)`. Note that this method is for `AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior` only.